# Electrical impulse through a mic

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity

For a typical mic a singer uses to sing on the stage, how much electrical current is generated when the sound gets converted into electrical impulses? Can I get an electric shock from the energy generated?

Comment: Your question cannot be answered as the necessary information about the type of microphone which a singer might be using has not been given by you.

Comment: Just any typical mic. Nothing specific here. Just want a general idea of its magnitude. Say Taylor Swift's mic, the one she used in her 1989 Tour in Singapore.

Comment: So why not look it up on the Internet? For example Taylor performed at the 58th Annual Grammy Awards in 2016, using the [Sennheiser SKM 9000](https://soniccircus.com/product/sennheiser-skm-9000-digital-handheld-transmitter/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typical mics generate anywhere from tens of millivolts to almost a volt (in some antique designs) but the *current* which accompanies those voltages is on the order of microamps. This means there is no way you can get any sort of electrical shock from the mic *output lines*.

HOWEVER if the amplifier system that the mic is plugged into has an improperly wired ground, it's possible for the microphone casing to be at MAINS VOLTAGE and if you touch it while standing on a well-grounded stage, you can get a lethal shock.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Given me a bit of an idea.